# How to show ProgressBar in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to show a ProgressBar while doing some activity as ProgressDialog is deprecated Xamarin.Android. I have searched everywhere, but I didn't find how to implement ProgressBar. This is my XML code:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/ProgressBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal" />
```

I am able to show the progress bar, but how to show it progressing while doing some activity like incrementing counter till 100.

Answer (score 1):

The ProgressBar control has a property called [Progress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.widget.progressbar.progress?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9#Android_Widget_ProgressBar_Progress) which you need to modify. By default, the minimum and maximum values are 0 and 100, so you don't even need to change them.

In a nutshell, you can update the progress in the activity like this:

```
var pb = FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.ProgressBar);

pb.Progress = 25;
// or alternatively
pb.IncrementProgressBy(30);
```

You can also define the starting progress in your XML like the following:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/ProgressBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:progress="25"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal" />
```